# convert object to array of key-value object

Tags: vega

I have a dataset like:

```
{'x': 70, 'y':30}
```

I want to convert it to an array of kv object to draw a pie chart with vega!!
How can i convert it to below in `Vega v4`? which `Transform` can do this?

```
[
{key: 'x', value: 70},
{key: 'y', value: 30}
]
```

Comment: Please specify whether you want a solution in Vega or in Vega-Lite: you've included both tags on your question.

Comment: @jakevdp sorry, i corrected this

Answer (score 1):

you can fold [transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/fold/)

```
  {
    "values": {"x": 70, "y": 30},
    "transform": [
      {
        "type": "fold",
        "fields": ["x", "y"],
        "as": ["page", "value"]
      }
    ]
  }
```